# Lotus Notes: Not allowed to access System Properties file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I added this code to load the system properties file in Java Agent but i am getting error as allowed to access system properties.

I want to load the abcd properties file  which is in Windows server in C drive From there properties file is going to be picked from the code.

```
inp = new FileInputStream("/abcd.properties");

    if(inp== null)
        {
            System.out.println("FIND NOT FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("FIND FOUND");
        }

    p.load(inp);
    System.out.println(p.getProperty("flag"));
```

I tried removing the

```
java.lang.SecurityException: not allowed to access system properties
08/22/2016 12:47:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
08/22/2016 12:47:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:342)
08/22/2016 12:47:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:73)
08/22/2016 12:47:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
08/22/2016 12:47:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @Duston can you help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting "Runtime security level" to 2 in order to allow access to the file system:

[image]

Comment: I have done the allow Restricted operations Options.

Comment: @umeli  I have changed it but still System properties i am not able to load

Comment: Have you tried to run the agent on level 3 ? And with all permissions granted in java.policy ?

Answer (score 0):

For those that may have similar issues, this is as a result of the JVM's Security Manager not allowing access to the system's properties. 
To allow access to the system, the security policy must specify this action, so the solution will be to change the security policy of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), which in turn will allow access to the system properties. 
Please visit: [www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173567](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173567) for a detailed solution.