# Lotus Notes : properties file couldnt not be found and loaded

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I am new to lotus and I am trying to pull the properties data from the server in **Java Agent** and I am getting error that file is not found and one thing is if I use `ff.load` method it is giving error as cannot access properties file.

Can any one tell what I have to add it in this code such that it would work correctly. I have corrected restriction rights also. and select the second option

Java Code.

```
InputStream con = session.getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:/pqrs.properties");
if(con== null)
            {
                System.out.println("FLAG FILE NOT FOUNDFIND NOT FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("FLAG FILE FOUND !!!!!!!!FIND FOUND");
            }

            Properties ff = new Properties();
            ff.load(con);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OS's filesystem security settings are probably not allowing the Domino server to read files from the root directory of the C: drive.

Try moving the file into a location that you know for sure that the Domino server can read. E.g, the C:\IBM\Lotus\Domino\Data folder - or whatever the equivalent location is in your Domino server's configuration.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075349/lotus-notes-not-allowed-to-access-system-properties-file for more info